# Add specialized methods to a class template without SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to define a bunch of generic code in a class template, and then add some functionality that's specific to some template parameter values. In short :

```cpp
// A vector of linear algebra
template <int n>
struct Vector
{
    // A bunch of functions not relying on a specific value for n
    float norm() { ... }
    float dot(const Vector& other) { ... }
private:
    float _data[n];
};
```

This is all well and good, but 3D vectors specifically have a 2-component cross product, while vectors in other dimensions don't (well, some do but that's not what this is about). I could use SFINAE to make it so a `cross` function is only defined for n = 3, however I would prefer being able to define all the functions that don't depend on a specific value of n together, and then implement the rest in independent template specializations.

When looking around, I've seen the idea of inheriting from the class template entertained, but then I don't want to have to redeclare a new type. Furthermore, this apparently does not work (somewhat expectedly) :

```cpp
template <>
struct Vector<3> : public Vector<3> // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Vector<3>’
{
    Vector cross(const Vector& other) { ... }
};
```

To put it differently, I want to specialize my `Vector` class but keep all the functions already defined in the class template, only adding more.

Is there any alternative to SFINAE, or is it my only option ?

Comment: you should put all functions that do not depend on `n` in a base class. What do you mean with ".. but then I don't want to have to redeclare a new type" ? If you want specializations for different values of `n`, those are "new types"

Comment: " I want to specialize my Vector class but keep all the functions already defined in the class template, only adding more." it doesnt work that way. In a specialization you do have to repeat all common methods (or put them in a base class)

Comment: 1st comment : `Vector` is that base class. And by not wanting to add new types, I meant that I want to be able to use the extra functions on `Vector<3>`, as opposed to introducing a different type name.

2nd comment : yes, I am aware of that, hence this question, where I am asking if there is a way to achieve what I'm asking.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you mean by "base class". If I have a `template <int n> struct VectorBase` with all the functions currently in the `struct Vector` from my example code, and have `template <int n> Vector : public VectorBase<n> { };` and specialize this, then I guess I get the effect that I wanted. Thanks ? :P I'll try this out before making an answer out of this.

Comment: If it's an consolation, you could simply write `auto cross (const Vector& other) requires (n == 3)` in C++20. Barring that, you only have the techniques you listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand what you exactly want... but seems to me that you're looking for a sort of self-inheritance as follows

```
// common part
template <int N, bool = N==3>
struct Vect
 {
   float foo_1 () { return 1.0f; }

   float _data[N];
 };

// additional methods for N==3 only
template <int N>
struct Vect<N, true> : public Vect<N, false>
 {
   float foo_2 () { return 2.0f; }

   // other additional methods
 };
```

that you can use in this way

```
   Vect<1>  v1;
   Vect<3>  v3;

   v1.foo_1();
   // v1.foo_2();  compilation error

   v3.foo_1();
   v3.foo_2();  // compile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common template alias to pull in the additional functionality if a condition is met.

```
template <int n>
struct Vector_impl {
    // base implementation
}

struct Vector_3_impl : Vector_impl<3> {
    // n == 3 specific implementation
}

template <int n>
using Vector = std::conditional_t<n == 3, Vector_3_impl, Vector_impl<n>>;
```